# Dependent does not work while binding relations in __construct function - CAKEPHP

Tags: cakephp

Actually in my scenario I am binding relations in model's constructor function. Actually I need to use a model attribute in my model relationship and Cakephp preventing using model attribute in default relationships. So I can't use

```
public $hasMany = array(
        'ProductDetail' => array(
            'className' => 'ProductDetail',
            'conditions' => array(
                'ProductDetail.language_id' => $this->languageId //Throws error
            ),
            'dependent' => true
        ),
    );
```

So I made a trick. I did bind model relations on model's `__construct()` function. Below is my code

```
public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
        parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);
        $this->bindModel(array(
            "hasMany" => array(
                'ProductDetail' => array(
                    'className' => 'ProductDetail',
                    'dependent' => true,
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'ProductDetail.language_id' => $this->languageId //Doesn't throw an error
                    )
                )
            )
                )
        );
    }
```

This trick works for me in each scenario. But when I delete a product, dependent model can't be deleted when I am binding relations under `__construct()` function. Is there any way to make this trick works or I need to trigger dependent functionality manually ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing research I found that pass second parameter to `false` on `bindModel` function. Because this will make your on-the-fly binding last the duration of the request. So in that case `Model::bindModel` function looks like

```
$this->bindModel(array(
            "hasMany" => array(
                'ProductDetail' => array(
                    'className' => 'ProductDetail',
                    'dependent' => true,
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'ProductDetail.language_id' => $this->languageId
                    )
                )
            )
                ), false
        );
```